# Finding the probability limit of $n^{1/4} \hat{\theta}$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Suppose that $n^{1/3} \hat{\theta} = O_{p}(1)$.

I want to find the probability limit of $n^{1/4} \hat{\theta}$ .

I have to use the following definition and lemma:

**Definition:** A sequence of random variables $\left \{ x_{n} \right \}$ is bounded in probability if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $b_{\epsilon} < \infty$ and integer $N$ such that $$P\left [ \left | x_{n} \right |\geq b_{\epsilon} \right ]<\epsilon$$
for all $N \geq N_{\epsilon}$. Then we write $x_{N}= O_{p}(1)$.

**Lemma:** If $x_{N}\overset{p}{\rightarrow}a$ then $x_{N}= O_{p}(1)$.

I am quite not sure how to start so any help would be appreciated.

But intuitively, will we also have $n^{1/4} \hat{\theta} = O_{p}(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_n:=n^{1/3}\hat{\theta}_n$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(|n^{-1/12}X_n|>\epsilon)=\mathsf{P}(|X_n|>n^{1/12}\epsilon)<\epsilon
$$
for all $n$ large enough ($\because X_n=O_p(1)$). It means that $n^{1/4}\hat{\theta}_n=o_p(1)$.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. But I didn't understand how you have $-1/12$ for $n$ as a power. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @OGC $n^{1/3}n^{-1/12}=n^{1/4}$.